# intel xdk cordova build not working on windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

I am building my cordova based app using Intel XDK. I was able to download the app from their secure link. It works fine on android device and my windows 8.1 PC.

When I try to install it on my windows 8.1 phone, it fails. I opened the provided zip and clicked on Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file. It shows a message, "There was a problem extracting it".

I've tried connecting the phone to my computer and copied the extracted files and then clicked on the .ps1 file. But still it fails.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 8 build system is not a "universal" Windows build system. It only builds for Windows 8, not for Windows Phone 8. To build for Windows Phone 8, with the current build system, please see this forum post for instructions on how to do this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/563699

A future release of the XDK will make this easier to do, for now, this "beta" procedure is what you have to use.

Comment: I tried this but the build failed. The log gives an error - Platform "wp81" not recognized as core cordova platform.

Comment: I just performed a test that follows the instructions in the link I provided and successfully created a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Please double-check your process. The summary log will say "Windows 8" but the app package provided is a Windows Phone 8.1 package. This is provided as a beta test tool, thus the reason for the confusing messages.

Comment: Yes it worked this time..I have APPXBUNDLE File rather than .ps1 file. But I do have a different issue, I was searching on how to run this file, but my Application Deployment tool does not seem to recognize it. It is only looking for XAP file. Any idea?

Comment: The simplest approach I've found is to use the [Windows Phone 8.1 Application Deployment Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn632395.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (but it does require that you've got an appropriate version of Visual Studio on your Windows system -- I believe [the free community edition](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads) will work).